# Webview with Ionic Or Phonegap

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, webview

I am using the plugin Ionic Native Transitions.

Problem is that when link transitions to another, I see a black background between the transitions. I don't want to see that black background. I want to see the splash screen. For this, I'd have to change the webview background itself. Changing CSS files got me nowhere.

I thought I could experiment, and I changed android:windowBackground with theme.xml. That was supposed to work with Android, but it hasn't. Besides I need the solution to work with the iPhone as well.

Answer (score 0):

In ionic framework version 1.3.1, the transitions between views are smooth and fast. There won't be flickering in this version of ionic. This version of ionic will provide native transitions between views. You can disable this native transition if you don't like using the following code in your config module

```
app.config(['$ionicConfigProvider',function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('none');
 }])
```

For more info refer [ionic nav doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/navTransition/) and [ionic config provider doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/)